# Why does the average linkage method put more emphasis on greater homogeneity then the Centroid Method?

Tags: clustering, heteroscedasticity

*at first i have to admit that i'am not an native english speaker. I hope i can articulate myself clearly. I read that the average linkage methode put more emphasis on greater homogeneity then the Centroid Method. And it appears that in my clustering the centroid method tend to create bigger cluster and cluster with long extended shapes, more quickly then the average method. But i can't explain myself why. Could you please help me with that question?*

Maybe i should overthink my questioning. Lets forget about the source. Both of these methods tend to create extendet shape clusters. Wich is based on  the fact that both of them compare means, so that bigger values graduate the smaller ones. In Fact I received this bigger and long extended shapes cluster, more quickly with the centroid method then in the average method. Now i am looking for an explaination for this phenomenon. I Assume its because the average linkage method weighted the calculation of the distances with the number of objects of clusters. The centroid method dont include this.

Comment: Where did you read that? Was it a reliable source? Because "homogeneity" is usually define with respect to a second labeling, which is not available to either. So *neither* should be able to put any emphasis on homogeneity...

Comment: Maybe i should overthink my questioning. Lets forget about the source. In Fact I received this bigger and long extended shapes cluster, more quickly with the centroid method then in the average method. Now i am looking for an explaination for this phenomenon.

Comment: Your new version is similarly undefined: what are "extended",.  "bigger", "long"? Doesn't single-linkage have the strongest tendency to create "long" and "extended" clusters? Why focus on the ill-defined centroid method that is known to produce anomalies?